# Job is getting called multiple times in quartz scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I'm running a batch job using quartz scheduler and cron expression, but the job is getting called multiple times in a loop.

Here is the configuration

```
public static void main(String[] args) {            
        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   
                "classpath:/execs/execJob.xml" 
            };

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);       

}
```

In execJob.xml-

```
<import resource="classpath:/schedulers/BatchLaunch.xml" />
```

In BatchLaunch.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:/environment/springBatchDbContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/environment/simpleJobEnvironment.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:/jobs/Job.xml" />


<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="triggers">

            <ref bean="JobTrigger" />

    </property>
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="job" value-ref="job" />
            <entry key="jobLauncher" value-ref="jobLauncher"/>
            <entry key="jobLocator" value-ref="jobRegistry"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="JobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="JobSchedule!{receive.recon.file.schedule}" />
</bean>



  <bean id="JobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.abc.scheduler.JobLauncherDetails" />
     <property name="group" value="quartz-batch" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="jobName" value="Job"/>
             <entry key="reconTimestamp" value="JobSchedule!{receive.recon.file.schedule.timestamp}"/>

        </map>
    </property>
</bean>




<bean id="quartzPlaceholderProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="location" value="classpath:reconCronSchedule.properties" />
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="JobSchedule!{" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}" />
</bean>
```

Here is the cron

```
receive.recon.file.schedule=* */10 * * * ?
receive.recon.file.schedule.timestamp=2014-03-01 00:00:00
```

Bellow is the log file:

```
    2015-02-06 11:44:27  INFO   jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
2015-02-06 11:44:28  INFO   launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor. 
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2015-02-06 11:44:29  INFO   context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647 
2015-02-06 11:44:29  INFO   scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now 
Done
2015-02-06 11:44:29  INFO   launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=Job]] launched with the following parameters: [{reconTimestamp=2014-03-01 00:00:00, timestamp=1423203269076}] 
2015-02-06 11:44:29  INFO   launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=Job]] launched with the following parameters: [{reconTimestamp=2014-03-01 00:00:00, timestamp=1423203269075}] 
2015-02-06 11:44:29  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [deleteFromLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [deleteFromLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=Job]] launched with the following parameters: [{reconTimestamp=2014-03-01 00:00:00, timestamp=1423203270003}] 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [deleteFromLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - Inside DeleteLineImportTasklet:::::: PC - 1 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - Inside DeleteLineImportTasklet:::::: PC - 1 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - Inside DeleteLineImportTasklet:::::: PC - 1 
2015-02-06 11:44:30  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - process Executed 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=Job]] launched with the following parameters: [{reconTimestamp=2014-03-01 00:00:00, timestamp=1423203271002}] 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - process Executed 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - process Executed 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [deleteFromLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - Inside DeleteLineImportTasklet:::::: PC - 1 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.delLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.tasklet.DeleteLineImportTasklet - process Executed 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [insertIntoLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [insertIntoLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [insertIntoLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Inside ReadReconDataForProcessorTasklet Tasklet  ::: PC - 2 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>0 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>1 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>2 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>3 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>4 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>5 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>6 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>7 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>8 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>9 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Writting successfull 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Inside ReadReconDataForProcessorTasklet Tasklet  ::: PC - 2 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>10 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>11 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>12 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>13 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>14 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>15 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>16 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>17 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>18 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>19 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Inside ReadReconDataForProcessorTasklet Tasklet  ::: PC - 2 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Writting successfull 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>20 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>21 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>22 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>23 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>24 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>25 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>26 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>27 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>28 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>29 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Writting successfull 
2015-02-06 11:44:31  INFO   core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [insertIntoLineImport] 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Inside ReadReconDataForProcessorTasklet Tasklet  ::: PC - 2 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Entry into com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>30 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>31 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>32 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>33 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>34 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>35 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>36 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>37 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>38 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Reading Record NO ==============>39 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=Job]] launched with the following parameters: [{reconTimestamp=2014-03-01 00:00:00, timestamp=1423203272001}] 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   dao.impl.ReconDaoImpl - Exit from com.abc.reconandsettlement.dao.impl.insertLineImport() 
2015-02-06 11:44:32  INFO   reconandsettlement.writer.ReconLineWritter - Writting successfull
```

Here the tasklets are called again and again.
Can anyone please suggest what is happening here ? 
am I missing any configuration or doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Could you please make sure that `com.abc.scheduler.JobLauncherDetails` class is not declared as a bean in `springBatchDbContext.xml` and `simpleJobEnvironment.xml`.

Comment: No, Its not declared there . These two xmls contains only db and job related beans.

Comment: Could you please share the details of `classpath:/jobs/Job.xml`?

Comment: That xml is having tasklets and supporting beans,nothing else.
In fact it works perfectly when I run it through a main class or trigger it from the UI.
This problem started when I integrated quartz for scheduling of jobs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opps !!!
I was doing a foolish thing.
It was all in cron expression,
I was scheduling it for every second.

Comment: right expression is "0 0/1 * * * ?" to run it on every 10 minuts.
I just kept * instead of 0 in the seconds place unknowingly.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this problem. Our case is that we configued a bean in applicationContext.xml but we also used :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/config/applicationContext.xml");
```

so, there are two beans totally.So our task execute two times. 
Lately, we changed this:

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) BeanUtils.getBean("beanName", MyBean.class);
```

everything is OK.

This is BeanUtils:

```
public final class BeanUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
    return applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
}

public static <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> clazs) {
    return clazs.cast(getBean(beanName));
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
    BeanUtils.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case it gets executed many times(not twice or thrice), and also I'm not calling any bean multiple times. Thanks for your reply